# Write $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n 2^i + 2^{n+1}$ as a single summation: any guidance?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm working on an assignment for Discrete Math, and sort of stuck on this question. I'm finding it a bit challenging to wrap my head around some of these concepts doing it remotely, and being removed from other students doing it.

Anyway: I'm kind of confused - $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n 2^i + 2^{n+1}$ seems to be a single summation already.

The direction I was going was that by Theorem 1 in my textbook for a geometric sum
$\sum\limits_{i=0}^n 2^i = 2^{n+1} - 1$

So I was thinking the entire statement would be equal to $2^{n+2} - 1$ (edited from a silly mistake: $4^{n+1} - 1$), but that doesn't really seem to line up with what the question is asking.

Thanks in advance for your patience and advice.

Comment: Can you clarify the implicit parenthesis? Is it $ (\sum 2^i) + 2^{n+1}$ or $\sum ( 2^i + 2^{n+1})$? The former isn't yet a "single summation", because it has a "leftover term".

Comment: Unfortunately I've written it exactly how it was presented in the assignment. I may have to reach out to my professor.

Comment: Did your prof (notes/lectures) define how to deal with $ \sum a + b$ for scenarios like this? It's one reason why people avoid having "leftover terms" at the end, and instead move them in front or use parenthesis. I believe your prof wanted the former scenario. In that case, do you see how to make it into a single summation?

Comment: Okay - that's a good point. I'll reread my notes with that at front of mind. Thank you so much for the quick response.

Comment: Without brackets, I would definitely read it as a sum plus a single extra term. Don't you think that “simple summation” just means that it's supposed to be rewritten as $\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} 2^i$?

Comment: I got this from my professor as a hint: 

"It is almost written as a single summation. If you see it carefully, you still can optimize (as a single summation) it."

Comment: @HansLundmark, I agree. (I was composing an answer to this effect and didn't see your comment till after.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's only $2^i$, not $2^i+2^{n+1}$, that's being summed, you can rewrite $\sum_{i=0}^n2^i+2^{n+1}$ as a single summation as follows:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n2^i+2^{n+1}=\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}2^i$$

Presumably this is an exercise in manipulating summation notation, which can be a useful thing to know how to do.

Comment: Ah, I see Hans Lundmark said much the same thing in a comment beneath the OP.

Comment: Hmm tricky, actually, but that makes a lot of sense. I have a feeling this is correct, as we did discus the idea of shifting the index!

I have to learn how to get out of my own head with this stuff - I tend to over-complicate and dig too deep into the toolbox, derailing my own solutions.

Comment: Well, writing it as an answer was actually a better idea, so +1 from me!

Comment: @RejFredericks, my goal (and lot) in life has been to make a virtue of simplemindedness ;-)

Comment: @BarryCipra I've gotten good at it in my old career as a songwriter, but coming back to STEM it's been a a daunting road! Practice makes perfect, though! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If the expression means $\sum_{i=0}^n(2^i+2^{n+1})$, since $i$ takes $n+1$ values the result is$$2^{n+1}-1+(n+1)2^{n+1}=(n+2)2^{n+1}-1.$$If the expression means $(\sum_{i=0}^n2^i)+2^{n+1}$, the result is$$2^{n+1}-1+2^{n+1}=2\cdot2^{n+1}-1=2^{n+2}-1.$$The latter meaning is more likely, as this calculation provides the inductive step in proving $\sum_{i=0}^n2^i=2^{n+1}-1$.

Comment: Thanks for the clear response! I'll use this to study more thoroughly.

Also - thank you for exposing my stupid arithmetic error adding those n+1 exponents! Editing that now.  The second method was what I was trying to communicate as my current thought process, so it's a relief to see I wasn't miles off base.  I'm still trying to wrap my head around more abstract maths, even though this is just the beginning.